# Perform tap on screen programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, screen, tap

Is there a way to perform a tap on screen programmatically?

I need to access a button of a framework that is not accessible programmatically, just by the user tap.

So, I need to simulate a tap as the user was tapping the screen, and the component in that position will respond, a button for example.

Comment: Why do you need to simulate a tap? Is this part of some UI testing? You should update your question with more specific details about what problem you are really trying to solve.

Comment: I need to access a button of a framework that is not accessible programatically, just by the user tap.

Comment: As I said, update your question with all relevant details.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something I used in tests:

```
class TouchMock: UITouch {
    var y: CGFloat

    init(y: CGFloat) {
        self.y = y
        super.init()
    }

    override func location(in view: UIView?) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: 10, y: y)
    }
}

func sendTouchesBegan(y: CGFloat, to view: UIView) {
    let touch = TouchMock(y: y)
    view.touchesBegan([touch], with: nil)
}

func sendTouchesMoved(y: CGFloat, to view: UIView) {
    let touch = TouchMock(y: y)
    view.touchesMoved([touch], with: nil)
}

func sendTouchesEnded(y: CGFloat, to view: UIView) {
    let touch = TouchMock(y: y)
    view.touchesEnded([touch], with: nil)
}

func sendTouchesCancelled(y: CGFloat, to view: UIView) {
    let touch = TouchMock(y: y)
    view.touchesCancelled([touch], with: nil)
}
```

Important: For me only the Y-coordinate was interesting. Adding X-coordinate is trivial of course.

Comment: Did not work. I tried with a coordinate of a button, but this button was not pressed.

Comment: Try   UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.sendEvent

Comment: @LeMag It's the position **inside** the button. So the position of the button itself inside it's superview won't work eh. Just try (1, 1) for example.

Comment: @CarlosAndresChaguendoSanche I do not know this code, could you be more specific?